# How do I locate the ceiling joists in my kitchen addition?

Tags: ceiling

My kitchen is an extension. I want to put ceiling hooks up there so I can hang pans from the ceiling.

I need to know where the rafters are so I'm not just putting hooks into the plaster. There is no access to the loft space.

Comment: Is the ceiling heavily textured?  Stud finders work on ceilings if not, and a magnet could work even if there is texture.

Comment: If you have modern drywall a simple knuckle knock will reveal them. The sound goes from hollow and booming to tighter and more solid. Use a very small drill bit to verify.

Comment: The ceiling is textured (looks like woodchip) and I can't rap it without hurting my hand because of all the sharp bits. I will try the stud finder

Comment: If the ceiling is too rough to knock on, it's probably too rough for a stud finder to work, so be aware of that.

Comment: ok. I'll just keep drilling until sawdust comes out ;)

Answer (score 1):

I like the rubber insulated handle of my screw driver as a knocking tool.  The rubber handle of a hammer works well, won't mar the ceiling.  A small finish nail leaves very little hole behind. (Happy Hunting) I carry an electronic stud finder as well. The newer stud finders are pretty amazing, fab results.  You don't need an expensive finder for impressive results.  I would avoid the low, low end models.